# How to listed to deleted event properly?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have records of a `Model` that I need to delete, however I need to delete their `id`'s also from the pivot table, so I tried to listed to deleted event, but it didn't work

Here is how I add the event:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Criteria extends Model {

    protected $table = 'criterias';

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleted(function($criteria)
        {
            DB::table('criteria_criteria')->where('criteria_id', '=', $criteria->id)->delete();
        });

    }


}
```

I am on `Laravel 5.1`, any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not used its relationship. Please create a `relationship` with your pivot table like this.

```
public function criteria()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Criteria');
}
```

This will automatically manage your deletion query on pivot table. It has also one benifit you can use its `sync` and `detach` methods to add and remove pivot table records.

For more detail you can read in this [tutorial](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) by search keyword `pivot`.